# Formatting text in CSS based on output text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using Awesome Tables (which I will refer to as AT) to take data from a Google Sheets document and present the data in a format I can embed into a website. I have used a HTML template in the sheets to display the data in the AT form, which utilises inline CSS formatting. The template is only for the table output and as such, only the `<body>` element exists for that table - i.e. I have no access to `<head>` section, etc.

I have a piece of data (${"Status"}) pulled in from Google Sheets that can insert one of three text outputs: Active, Delivered or Cancelled. This is called to the output by:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;color:rgb(87, 87, 87);font-size: 14px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;flex-shrink: 0;margin-right: auto;text-transform: capitalize;">
      <p><b>Name:</b> ${"Name"}</p>
      <p><b>Start Date:</b> ${"Start Date"}</p>
      <p><b>Completed Date:</b> ${"Completed Date"}</p>
      <p><b>Status:</b> ${"Status"}</p>
</div>
```

I would like to color format the output text of ${"Status"} so that "Active" = orange, "Cancelled" = red and "Delivered" = green but not 100% sure how to do this. I have read that I probably need to use some sort of JavaScript to achieve this, but to be honest, do not know where to start.

Any help appreciated.

---

So, following on from the response received, here is my first attempt of writing JavaScript after a bit of online research. Am I heading along the right track?

```
var jobStatus = "${"Status"}";

if (jobStatus = "Delivered") {
  document.getElementById("status").style.color = "green";
} else if (jobStatus = "Active") {
  document.getElementById("status").style.color = "orange";
} else {
  document.getElementById("status").style.color = "red";
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the template?

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the html template, I would suggest to use css classes to apply the colors. Therefore just apply the value also as the css class and create a bit of css to format your text (or what ever) how you want it:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;color:rgb(87, 87, 87);font-size: 14px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;flex-shrink: 0;margin-right: auto;text-transform: capitalize;">
  <p><b>Name:</b> ${"Name"}</p>
  <p><b>Start Date:</b> ${"Start Date"}</p>
  <p><b>Completed Date:</b> ${"Completed Date"}</p>
  <p class="${"Status"}"><b>Status:</b> ${"Status"}</p>
</div>
```

The css is static. You can put it in the header section of your document (I understood, you do not have dynamic access to that, is that assumption correct?). Otherwise some js to append it to the body would work as well.

```
.Active {
   color: orange;
}
.Cancelled {
   color: red;
}
.Delivered {
   color: green;
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response.You are correct that I do not have dynamic access to the HTML header. Although not preferred, would it work if I added a CSS <style> into the body?

Comment: Ignore - won't work - lol. I'll get it sussed - part of learning stuff :)